# Split text after a delimiter and store into array

Tags: arrays, bash, text, split, delimiter

I want to fetch a DNS zone in a text just after a delimiter 'name":"' and after to store into array:

```
[{"id":12,"**name":"43.11.in-addr.arpa**","ttl":1000,"nameserver":"mo.t1.ree.kalou.com.","email":"dns.kalou.com","serial":348,"refresh_time":1000,"negative_ttl":10800},{"id":13,"name":"**58.78.in-addr.arpa**","ttl":100 etc etc
```

the output of array:

```
43.11.in-addr.arpa
58.78.in-addr.arpa
```

I just find to split after a single delimiter but not a word.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a JSON text, parse it using a syntax aware parser, `jq` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your input looks like

```
your_json_string='[
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "43.11.in-addr.arpa",
    "ttl": 1000,
    "nameserver": "mo.t1.ree.kalou.com.",
    "email": "dns.kalou.com",
    "serial": 348,
    "refresh_time": 1000,
    "negative_ttl": 10800
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "58.78.in-addr.arpa",
    "ttl": 100
  }
]'
```

To extract the `name` field, you can use `jq`:

```
jq -r '.[].name' <<< "$your_json_string"
```

To assign the values to an array, use this:

```
my_array=($(jq -r '.[].name' <<< "$your_json_string"))
```

And possibly use it with something like

```
echo ${my_array[0]}
```

Comment: great, not how I can store the output jq into bash array please

Comment: @oliv: Just a note that, this logic would break i.e. `array=( $(cmd) )` if `cmd` emits content that has spaces. Thought it wouldn't apply to this case, but in general not advised to recommend this approach, need to use `mapfile`/`readarray` or use a `read` command